# How to Left Justify a Part of a Letter's Closing That is Also Centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, letters, center, justification

I am trying to mimic the following closings as seen, for example, in the following excerpt:

[image]

The following MWE provides an approximation to the first part of the closing; but, it's the second---which seems to be both left justified and centered---which is giving me the most trouble.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Our Blessed Saviour for His goodness to our Confraternity, and for our salvation through His Blood.

\vspace*{10pt}

\begin{flushright}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
    Your affectionate Servant and Father \\
    {\scshape{Frederick William Faber,}} \\
    Priest of the Oratory.
  \end{tabular}
\end{flushright}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{center}
\begin{small}
The London Oratory. \\
Feast of the Conversion of St. Paul. \\
1860.
\end{small}
\end{center}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Can someone suggest how I may get the three lines beginning with ``The London Oratory'' to resemble the excerpt above? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the `tabular` in the wrong place.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{baskervillef}

\begin{document}

Our Blessed Saviour for His goodness to our Confraternity,
and for our salvation through His Blood.

\vspace*{10pt}

\begin{flushright}
  Your affectionate Servant and Father\hspace*{1em} \\[1ex]
  \textsc{Frederick William Faber,}\hspace*{2em} \\[1ex]
  Priest of the Oratory.\hspace*{2em}
\end{flushright}

\begin{flushleft}\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
The London Oratory. \\
Feast of the Conversion of St. Paul. \\
1860.
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, as well as for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 3):

Something along this? By wrapping the text in a `minipage` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Our Blessed Saviour for His goodness to our Confraternity, and for our salvation through His Blood.

\vspace*{10pt}

\begin{flushright}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
    Your affectionate Servant and Father \\
    {\scshape{Frederick William Faber,}} \\
    Priest of the Oratory.
  \end{tabular}
\end{flushright}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} %Here!
\begin{center}
\begin{small}
The London Oratory. \\
Feast of the Conversion of St. Paul. \\
1860.
\end{small}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:  I also tried `\hangindent` and `\handafter`, but using `\rightskip` was easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\vbox{\raggedleft
\rightskip=1em
Your affectionate Servant and Father\par
\rightskip=2em
{\scshape{Frederick William Faber,}} \\
Priest of the Oratory.}

\end{document}
```